# Unable to find out the feature importance list from histgradientboosting classifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, gradient-descent

Is there any way to find the feature importances from a histgradientboosting classifier model in python?

I tried using model.feature_importances_ but the error message was

```
AttributeError: 'HistGradientBoostingClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

I wanted to get all the features in a list with percentage of importance of each feature.

Comment: If you look for a predefiened funciton: there is currently no function for histgradientboosting to calculate the feature importance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you could try is: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html

Comment: Thanks @PV8. for your answer. Although I was looking for a specific code if there is any in scikit learn or any other library to check the feature importance but your suggestion helps me a bit.